# REST api with C#.NET complex json data in body posting

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp

I want to use sms gateway in my app. that's why I've contact with an operator and the operator give me a api format.

URL: https://ideabiz.lk/apicall/smsmessaging/v2/outbound/3313/requests

Request header

```
Content-Type: application/json 
Authorization: Bearer [access token] 
Accept: application/json
```

Body

```
{
    "outboundSMSMessageRequest": {
        "address": [
            "tel:+94771234567"
        ],
        "senderAddress": "tel:12345678",
        "outboundSMSTextMessage": {
            "message": "Test Message"
        },
        "clientCorrelator": "123456",
        "receiptRequest": {
            "notifyURL": "http://128.199.174.220:1080/sms/report",
            "callbackData": "some-data-useful-to-the-requester"
        },
        "senderName": "ACME Inc."
    }
}
```

---

Now, I've code it :

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(@"https://ideabiz.lk/");
RestRequest req = new RestRequest(@"apicall/smsmessaging/v2/outbound/3313/requests", Method.POST);

req.AddHeader("Content-Type", @"application/json");
req.AddHeader("Authorization", @"Bearer " + accessToken.ToString());
req.AddHeader("Accept", @"application/json");

string jSon_Data = @"{'outboundSMSMessageRequest': {'address': ['tel:+94768769027'],'senderAddress': 'tel:3313','outboundSMSTextMessage': {'message': 'Test Message : " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "'},'clientCorrelator': '123456','receiptRequest': {'notifyURL': 'http://128.199.174.220:1080/sms/report','callbackData': 'some-data-useful-to-the-requester'},'senderName': ''}}";


JObject json = JObject.Parse(jSon_Data);
req.AddBody(json);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(req);
string x = response.Content.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
```

---

When i execute this program, in the line

req.AddBody(json);

my system crash and give error message that:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

How can i post complex JSON by using C#.NET ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. You need to set `RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json` before the call to `AddBody`:

   ```
       req.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
       req.AddBody(json);
   ```

   Without setting the parameter, RestSharp tries to serialize the `JObject` *to XML* and falls into an infinite recursion somewhere -- most likely trying to serialize [`JToken.Parent`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parent.htm).
2. According to RestSharp's [readme.txt](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/v103.1/readme.txt) (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160116201552/https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/readme.txt)), starting in version 103.0, RestSharp no longer uses Json.NET as their JSON serializer:

   ```
   There is one breaking change: the default Json*Serializer* is no longer 
   compatible with Json.NET. To use Json.NET for serialization, copy the code 
   from https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/86b31f9adf049d7fb821de8279154f41a17b36f7/RestSharp/Serializers/JsonSerializer.cs 
   and register it with your client:

   var client = new RestClient();
   client.JsonSerializer = new YourCustomSerializer();
   ```

   RestSharp's new built-in JSON serializer doesn't understand `JObject` so you need to follow the instructions above if you are using one of these more recent versions, Create:

   ```
   public class JsonDotNetSerializer : ISerializer
   {
       private readonly Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer _serializer;

       /// <summary>
       /// Default serializer
       /// </summary>
       public JsonDotNetSerializer() {
           ContentType = "application/json";
           _serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer {
               MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
               NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,
               DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include
           };
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Default serializer with overload for allowing custom Json.NET settings
       /// </summary>
       public JsonDotNetSerializer(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer){
           ContentType = "application/json";
           _serializer = serializer;
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Serialize the object as JSON
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="obj">Object to serialize</param>
       /// <returns>JSON as String</returns>
       public string Serialize(object obj) {
           using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter()) {
               using (var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter)) {
                   jsonTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                   jsonTextWriter.QuoteChar = '"';

                   _serializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, obj);

                   var result = stringWriter.ToString();
                   return result;
               }
           }
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Unused for JSON Serialization
       /// </summary>
       public string DateFormat { get; set; }
       /// <summary>
       /// Unused for JSON Serialization
       /// </summary>
       public string RootElement { get; set; }
       /// <summary>
       /// Unused for JSON Serialization
       /// </summary>
       public string Namespace { get; set; }
       /// <summary>
       /// Content type for serialized content
       /// </summary>
       public string ContentType { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   And then do:

   ```
       RestRequest req = new RestRequest(@"apicall/smsmessaging/v2/outbound/3313/requests", Method.POST);
       req.JsonSerializer = new JsonDotNetSerializer();
   ```

**2023 update**.

As of [Release 107.0.0](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/releases/tag/107.0.0) the default JSON serializer for RestSharp is [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to). This serializer also doesn't understand `JObject`, but as of .NET 6 supports an equivalent built-in type type [`JsonObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonobject), so switching to [`System.Text.Json.Nodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom#use-jsonnode) for creating and deserializing free-form JSON is an option.

The RestSharp documentation documentation has been updated with a section [NewtonsoftJson (aka Json.Net)](https://restsharp.dev/serialization.html#newtonsoftjson-aka-json-net):

> RestSharp support Json.Net serializer via a separate package [RestSharp.Serializers.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp.Serializers.NewtonsoftJson)
>
> WARNING
>
> Please note that RestSharp.Newtonsoft.Json package is not provided by RestSharp, is marked as obsolete on NuGet, and no longer supported by its creator.

Comment: After Following this instruction, It's works fine. Thanks @dbc.